# Magento 2 call custom library in select.html

Tags: javascript, magento, knockout.js, magento2, dropdown

I need to call custom library for select. I have an issue calling this library on knockout files. Particularly for select that is being rendered with this file Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/select.html 
I have tried everything I found online but had no luck. Tried to extended select.js with new function and then call it on afterRender in this file,
tried usin x-magento-init, and so on.

I need to do this for this select: $('select').select2();

Can someone provide concrete and precise solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. The issue was that when I add call to custom library in select.js there was no jQuery in define, I needed to add jQuery. But after this I was getting error for this part 
return Abstract.extend as it's not jQuery function. Only after adding 'ko'
to define before jQuery I was able to write new function to be called inside afterRender method of UI module.